# Preferences creates a scroll bar in all my fragments

Tags: android, kotlin

I just created a Preferences fragment like the oficial guide says.

It works fine but when i return to my others fragments there is a scroll bar in all my fragments that have a RecyclerView.

```
class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {

override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
    setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey)
    } 

}
```

Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<SwitchPreference
    android:defaultValue="false"
    android:key="switch_preference_1"
    android:title="Switch preference" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Any ideas why is this happening and how to remove it?

[image]

Comment: Looks like a scroll bar. Are you sure the other fragment is really gone?

Comment: I dont think so, im using one activity with multiple fragments and destinations with ids to navigate the fragments and a top app bar, is that a problem?

Comment: if you use ScrollView or RecyclerView in UI, just set scroll bar to None:  `android:scrollbars="none"`

Answer (score 0):

I'm investigation this problem right now, there is a rough solution which "does the job".

```
    private fun turnOffScrollBars(view: View) {
        view.isHorizontalScrollBarEnabled = false
        view.isVerticalScrollBarEnabled = false
        if(view is ViewGroup)
            for(child in view.children) {
                turnOffScrollBars(child)
            }
    }
```

Call it on the MainActivity's main layout, it'll turn off every scrollbar in the MainActivity's view tree, although it's neither elegant nor a good solution.

Edit:

It seems like my PreferenceFragment sets isVerticalScrollBarEnabled to true on every single view in the view hierarchy whenever i call navigateUp back to the previous fragment.

Since it feels like a bug to me, i can only offer you a modified function to find the view that causes the scrollbar, thus you only need to turn it off only in that single view, if it doesn't cause problems in other views.

```
    private fun turnOffScrollBars(view: View, counter: Int) {
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            Thread.sleep(5000)
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                view.isHorizontalScrollBarEnabled = false
                view.isVerticalScrollBarEnabled = false
                
                println()
                repeat(counter) {
                    print('\t')
                }
                
                try {
                    print(view::class.java.toString() + " id:" + resources.getResourceEntryName(view.id) + " [scrollbar is turned off]")
                } catch (exception: Resources.NotFoundException) {
                    print(view::class.java.toString() + " id:" + "No Id" + " [scrollbar is turned off]")
                }

                if(view is ViewGroup)
                    for(child in view.children) {
                        turnOffScrollBars(child, counter + 1)
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

Start this function (for example, with a button) after returning from the PreferenceFragment calling it like:

```
turnOffScrollBars(myLayout, 0)
```

The function will turn off scrollbars in the view hierarchy one by one, print it to the console hierarchically with tabs, and it'll let you 5 seconds to check if the scrollbar still persits.

The output looks like this:

```
 class androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout id:layout [scrollbar is turned off]
    class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView id:nav_host_fragment [scrollbar is turned off]
        class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView id:nav_host_fragment [scrollbar is turned off]
            class android.widget.LinearLayout id:layout [scrollbar is turned off]
                class androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2 id:viewPager [scrollbar is turned off]
                class com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout id:tabLayout [scrollbar is turned off]
                    class androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2$RecyclerViewImpl id:No Id [scrollbar is turned off]
                    class com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout$SlidingTabIndicator id:No Id [scrollbar is turned off]
                        class android.widget.FrameLayout id:No Id [scrollbar is turned off]
                        class com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout$TabView id:No Id [scrollbar is turned off]
                        class com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout$TabView id:No Id [scrollbar is turned off]
                        class com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout$TabView id:No Id [scrollbar is turned off]
                            class android.widget.FrameLayout id:layout [scrollbar is turned off]
                            class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView id:No Id [scrollbar is turned off]
                            class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView id:No Id [scrollbar is turned off]
                            class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView id:No Id [scrollbar is turned off]
                            class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView id:No Id [scrollbar is turned off]
                            class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView id:No Id [scrollbar is turned off]
                            class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView id:No Id [scrollbar is turned off]
                                class androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2 id:viewPager [scrollbar is turned off]
                                    class androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2$RecyclerViewImpl id:No Id [scrollbar is turned off]
```

I've found that in one of my ViewPagers there is an inner RecyclerView. I've turned the vertical scroll bar off, and it fixed it for me.

```
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        viewPager.children.filter { view -> view is RecyclerView }.first().isVerticalScrollBarEnabled = false
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Hide Scrollbar in SettingsFragment (PreferencesFragment)

1. **Add Style in `values/themes.xml` (day, night, or both):**

   ```xml
   <style name="PreferenceFragmentStyle" parent="Base.Theme.AppName">
       <item name="android:scrollbarThumbVertical">@android:color/transparent</item>
       <item name="android:scrollbarTrackVertical">@android:color/transparent</item>
   </style>
   ```
2. **Apply Style in Your Desired Fragment (e.g., SettingsFragment):**

   ```kotlin
   override fun onCreateView(
       inflater: LayoutInflater,
       container: ViewGroup?,
       savedInstanceState: Bundle?
   ): View {
       context?.theme?.applyStyle(R.style.PreferenceFragmentStyle, true)
       return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
   }
   ```

This code will hide the vertical scrollbar in your `SettingsFragment`. Adjust the style and theme according to your project's setup.